# How to create usable file for loading as Java.utils.prefs.Preferences

Tags: java, xml, storing-data

I like to store database login information and some other informations in file. So I've found Preferences class, which provides some simple methods for storing this in a XML file.

But, how can I create such a XML File manually, for using this file in my application. Also how to place or reference this file in the code?

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic approach is to put your file in "resource" folder (should be on the same level with your "java" folder).

You can access this file by:

`ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = loader.getResource("your-file-name.xml");`

But note, that when using frameworks, all this staff is done behind the screen For example, when configuring Hibernate all you have to do is just to feed file name in configuration object:

`new Configuration("hibernate.cfg.xml").configure()`

and resolving and parsing this file is Hibernates job. So, before doing extra job, make sure that it's the only option.